# How to disable wireless network interface (wlp2s0)

Tags: command-line, wireless

```
sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 down
```

Does not work

Comment: What OS/release?   `ifconfig` has been depreciated so is not installed by default in later releases (replaced by `ip` command), but you didn't specify any details...

Comment: sometimes you need to kill processes that for some reason locks your interface, you can list them with ```lsof -nPi@127.0.0.1``` change ip first.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `iw` instead:

```
sudo iw dev wlp2s0 del
```

source: [Wireless Wiki at kernel.org](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw#deleting_interfaces_with_iw)

---

You can also use the `ip` command:

```
sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 down
```

source: [Redhat ip Command Cheatsheet](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_ip_command_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print.pdf) (uses example interface "em1" instead of "wlp2s0")